# Query Matching hasMany field in CakePHP

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-3.0, has-many

I can't find a working query that match my need.

I simply have a Bookings model and a Bookingsstatus :
`Bookings` hasMany `Bookingsstatus`

In that way, I can keep all changes to the status and when I want the status of a Booking, I just have to take the last associated entry.

BUT,
is there a query to get all Bookings currently matching a specific status ? (not a booking that has at some point the specific status)

I tried with matching but it's not working ... Does anyone has a lead ?
Thanks

Comment: Just write the code here...

Comment: Please always show the data (or equivalent samples) that you are working with, the context, the code required to reproduce the problem, your debugging attempts, and possible errors! In your case, please show a small set of `Bookings` and `Bookinsstatus`, an explanation of how a record is determined as being "_last_", and your matching attempts.

Comment: Hi can you put your code here and show us your entities to help you